# Can a chef workstations support several organizations?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a workstation and 3 organizations.

What happens if I apply the Chef.io starter kits for each organization on to the workstation?  Is there a 'belongs-to' relationship between Organization and Workstation that precludes the management of nodes from all organizations.

Do I startup a separate workstation for each instance? Separate user accounts on same workstation?

Doe's knife have a default organization and a switch for other organization?

Comment: The answer is 'Yes'. A single directory on a chef workstation can have multiple starter kits.  You would adjust what organization you are working in by cd'ing to the organization's starter kit.

Comment: Checkout the knife block plugin. Allows you to manage multiple knife configuration files. See: https://github.com/knife-block/knife-block